# Offering same functionality on browse and details page?

Tags: usability, master-details, visibility, browse

I’ve two pages: browse (parent) and details (child).

Browse has a list of items, displaying the name and some other meta data (description, owner, upload date, etc.). Clicking on an item opens the details page, which offers viewing and editing of the whole data in different sections.

On details there are also some handy actions, like: c/p URL, get code snippet or report a bug.

From a UX point of view, would it make sense to duplicate these actions in the Browse list? Basically adding them to every row/item to have quick access?

I fear that there might be an overload, as there are 4 actions and hundreds of results, which will cause number_displayed_items*4 more actionable elements on the view.

Answer (score 2):

When I need to have actions in a browse list, which is often, I have the primary action as a stand-alone button and other actions in a drop-down menu for quick access. This maximises space for information in the row and (imho) keeps it all nice and tidy.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too. The thing that concerns me with this, is that you still have to make a click here, but you could also just open the customer. As well as hiding functionality behind a dropdown. Trying to keep the site as lean as possible, eg. less is more.

Comment: Ultimately, it should be driven by what your user research identifies as the most commonly used functions and whether it warrants having the function available in the row, behind a drop-down or left on the details page. Actions in a drop-down have the benefit of not needing to take the user out of context of the item's position in a list, assuming they don't navigate away from said list.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if there is a need for that you need to find out how users would use this feature and what attention these tasks need and also the estimated number of actions a user will complete.

For example, if the user story claims that he needs to process 20 results per session, then it would be really bad to have him enter 20 separate pages and do this.

But if the task itself requires attention and responsibility and you want to avoid user error maybe having them visit each result and doing the edits in the child's page would make sense.

In this case maybe a usability study will help you determine it but have in mind that most apps with tables will allow users to manipulate rows from the results page as well.